# Running Maperitive on a Mac

Tags: openstreetmap, vector, mac, maperitive

Really basic question, but I need details and help running Maperitive from my mac. I've tried launching it from the terminal and tried running it through WineBottler. If anyone has experience with this, please help!

Comment: Do you have mono installed?

Comment: Stevetech is correct Mono is required to run Maperitive on the Mac http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen instructions on OSM's wiki page (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive#Mac_OS_X)?

BTW since I'm the author of Maperitive, I feel obliged to tell you that running on it Mac has a mixed success rate, based on the feedback I got from various users. It works for some, while not for the others and (since I don't own a Mac) I cannot really say why, but it probably has to do with some Mono compatibility issues. Some people use a Windows virtual machine instead.